# Prestashop throwing "technical error" when form autosubmit

Tags: javascript, prestashop, form-submit

Im developing a payment gateway module for Prestashop. When chosen on the payment type page of the checkout process, the customer is redirected to another website. The problem is that just before getting redirected Prestashop throws this error:

[image]

I believe this is a error from Prestashop, but as you can also see it does not really tell me anything. After i press OK, the redirection happens, and im able to complete a order without any further errors. Everything else is working fine without errors.

The way that specific page is working is with a hidden form that gets autosubmitted with javascript like so

```
<form action='http://paymentpage.com/blabla' method='post' name='redirectionForm'>
   <input type='hidden' name='returnUrl' value='http://welcomeback.com'>
   .....
</form>

<script language="javascript">
    document.redirectionForm.submit();
</script>
```

If i comment out the `document.redirectionForm.submit();` the error from the screenshot is not shown, but ofcourse the page is not redirected either.

The wierd part is that this error does not always get shown (8/10 times it does), and it only happens in Chrome.

Furthermore the Chrome debugger console shows nothing.

Can you guys assist ?